# How to iterate through tr class ,get value and do the conditions?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have following table: All the data here are dynamic, loaded from database.

```
<table>
   <tr class="items">
       <td>Name: <input type="text" class="name" value="Steven"></td>
       <td>Employed: <input type="text" class="emp_stat" value="Y"></td>
       <td>Minimum Salary: <input type="text" class="min_sal" value="200"></td>
       <td>Location: <input type="text" class="country" value="USA"></td> 
   </tr>
   <tr class="items">
       <td>Name: <input type="text" class="name" value="John"></td>
       <td>Employed: <input type="text" class="emp_stat" value="N"></td>
       <td>Minimum Salary: <input type="text" class="min_sal" value="0"></td>
       <td>Location: <input type="text" class="country" value="USA"></td> 
   </tr>
   <tr class="items">
       <td>Name: <input type="text" class="name" value="Mark"></td>
       <td>Employed: <input type="text" class="emp_stat" value="Y"></td>
       <td>Minimum Salary: <input type="text" class="min_sal" value="200"></td>
       <td>Location: <input type="text" class="country" value="USA"></td> 
   </tr>
</table>
<button id="btn_add">Add More</button> //will create new tr with inputs
<button id="btn_save">Save</button>

$('.items').each(function(){
       $emp_stat= $(this).find($('.emp_stat').text());
        $min_sal = $(this).find($('.min_sal').val());
        if($emp_stat == 'Y' && $min_sal < 100){
            alert('Min Salary must be above 100 $.');
        }else{
            //else do something
        }
});
```

What I want to do here is ; In all Employed Value = Y, say the Minimum salary must be 100 . If some one puts below hundred 100 want to give some sort of validation popup if clicked on save btn and for Employed Value = N, I want to disable minimum Salary inputs. How to do it? This is on edit/new page. on btn_add will add new  with inputs with same condition.

How to do in Jquery?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware that many do not just provide code. It is best to enter what you have so far, what you have tried, so that others can help correct the code you have or offer suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is wrong.

> $(this).find('.emp_stat').val()

> $(this).find('.min_sal').val()

this returns the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function checkSalary(row, salary) {
    // Given a Row element, check if 2nd Input is "Y" and then check if Salary is less than given Salary or 100
    if (salary == undefined) {
      salary = 100;
    }
    var result = false;
    if ($("td:eq(1) input", row).val() == "Y") {
      result = parseInt($("td:eq(2) input", row).val()) < 100;
    }
    // If less than 100, result will be false
    return result;
  }

  function checkAll(className) {
    // Assume all are correct
    var result = true;
    // Check Each Row, by given class name
    $(className).each(function(index, element) {
      var check = checkSalary(element);
      if (!check) {
        $(element).removeClass("alert");
      } else {
        $(element).addClass("alert");
      }
      // Combined verification
      // true && true = true
      // true && false = false
      result = result && check;
    });
    return result;
  }

  $("#btn_save").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return checkAll(".items");
  });
});
```

```css
.alert td:nth-child(3) input {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="items">
    <td>Name: <input type="text" value="Steven"></td>
    <td>Employed: <input type="text" value="Y"></td>
    <td>Minimum Salary: <input type="text" value="200"></td>
    <td>Location: <input type="text" value="USA"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="items">
    <td>Name: <input type="text" value="John"></td>
    <td>Employed: <input type="text" value="N"></td>
    <td>Minimum Salary: <input type="text" value="0"></td>
    <td>Location: <input type="text" value="USA"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="items">
    <td>Name: <input type="text" value="Mark"></td>
    <td>Employed: <input type="text" value="Y"></td>
    <td>Minimum Salary: <input type="text" value="200"></td>
    <td>Location: <input type="text" value="USA"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="btn_add">Add More</button>
<button id="btn_save">Save</button>
```

This is an example of a simple form verification method. It uses `.each()` to iterate each of the rows in a table. You have a specific condition, if Employed is "Y", then check the Salary is high enough.